# Find word not surrounded by alpha char

Tags: python, regex

After some search this seems more difficult than I thought: I am trying to write a regular expression in Python to find a word which is not surrounded by other letters or dashes.

In the following examples, I am trying to match `ios`:

1. It seems carpedios
2. I like "ios" because they have blue products
3. I like carpedios and ios
4. I like carpedios and ios.
5. i like carped-ios

The matches should be as follows:

- 1: don't match because `ios` is after `d`.
- 2: match because `ios` is not surrounded by letters.
- 3: match because one of `ios` is not surrounded by letters.
- 4: match because one of `ios` is not surrounded by letters.
- 5: don't match because `ios` is followed by `-`.

How to do it with regex?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I use python language in my present case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following one should suit your needs:

```
(?<!-)\bios\b(?!-)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/keVaobtDmJSpjv_1)

Comment: And yes, Python does support look(?:ahead|behind).

Comment: I updated the link to use "Python" instead of "PCRE". No visible change until you click on it. Hope you don't mind. Thanks for introducing me to debuggex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\b` to match the empty string at the start or end of a word.
However, to also disallow `-` we have to use a character class containing
both, then invert it. That would look something like this:

```
[^\b-]
```

Let's pick that apart. `[]` is the character class itself. `^` at the start
says to invert the match, so only characters not in the character class
match. Note that `-` has to come last (or perhaps first) in a character class,
otherwise it will be mistaken for a range. (This allows you to say `[0-9a-fA-F]` as
a shorthand for all hexadecimals.)

Let's try it! Here's your test file:

```
$ cat t.txt
It seems carpedios
I like "ios" because they have blue products
I like carpedios and ios
I like carpedios and ios.
i like carped-ios
```

Let's put together our pattern using the character classes above:

```
$ grep '[^\b-]ios[^\b-]' t.txt
I like "ios" because they have blue products
I like carpedios and ios
I like carpedios and ios.
```

Hope this helps!

*Update:* I notice there's a good alternative answer, but I hope this adds some extra explanation.

Comment: This is explicitly a Python question.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that. I'll rework to show with `\b`, which is supported by Python also.

Comment: Your final solution is still using `grep` :-)

Comment: The solution is _showing that the regex works_ using grep, yes, but the regex itself should work in python too. Regexes are fairly portable across languages, particularly simple ones like this!

Comment: Fair enough. I do like the fact that you don't use look ahead or behind. Making a small edit so I can flip my vote :-)

Answer (score -1):

Something like: `[^a-zA-Z\-](ios)[^a-zA-Z\-]`

Might however be problematic at the beginning or the end of a line

Comment: And surrounding chars will be matched as well.

Comment: Tested it. Doesn't match `I like carpedios and ios`, like you said. So you are not fulfilling the OP's basic requirement.

Comment: Yes as the ios it would have to match is at the end of the line, which is problematic with my answer, as I mentioned. Moreover at the time of my answer the question was not yet tagged with python …